# Отправка изображений с сервера telegram bot

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

у меня есть Telegram bot которому я отправляю изображение и по логике он должен отправить это фото другому пользователю.
Собственно я достиг того что могу получить изображение в формате

```
https://api.telegram.org/file/bot<token>/<file_path>
```

Собственно далее я отправляю нужному пользователю это фото

```
    if($photo){
    $params_photo = [
        'file_id' => $photo_id
        
    ];
    
    $photo_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$token.'/getFile?'.http_build_query($params_photo)), TRUE);

    file_put_contents('photo.txt', '$data: '.print_r($photo_data, 1)."\n", FILE_APPEND);
    $photo_path = $photo_data['result']['file_path'];
    $params2 = [
        'chat_id' => $data['message']['chat']['id'],
        'photo' => 'https://api.telegram.org/file/bot'.$token.'/'.$photo_path
    ];
    file_get_contents('https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$token.'/sendPhoto?'.http_build_query($params2));
}
```

ну и вместо полученного изображения я получаю ошибку в error_log

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://api.telegram.org/bot.../sendPhoto?chat_id=64038730&amp;photo=...Fphotos%2Ffile_6.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

Comment: curl'ом загружайте

Answer (score 0):

> file_get_contents('https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$token.'/sendPhoto?'.http_build_query($params2));

Попробуйте использовать функцию `urldecode`

Замените на этот код:

```
file_get_contents('https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$token.'/sendPhoto?'.urldecode(http_build_query($params2)));
```